# When do React PropTypes get initialized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am having an issue with required `PropTypes` throwing errors. I would expect the `PropType` to throw an error if the `Component` was was being directly rendered. Here is a small sample of what I am trying to achieve.

You'll notice that the `Button` prop has a required `PropType` of handle click.

But I want the implementation of a `Modal` to be as simple as possible.
And since I don't have the context of Modal I can not bind the `handleClick` method directly to the `Button` so I pass the `Button` in as child and map over the children adding the `handleClick` method to the child component. This works pretty well besides throwing the error for `Button` because `<Button>` gets called and checked before it truly gets rendered.

I have tried to do this a few other ways as well using Higher Order Components which worked as well. But the implementation seemed convoluted and tedious this seems like a much simpler way to just generate a `Modal` when it is needed. You don't need any props you just pass in a child component and it will add the click handler.

It would be awesome to either Bypass the proptypes check until it is actually rendered in `Modal` Component or maybe there is a simpler way, all feed back is welcomed.

https://jsfiddle.net/kriscoulson/00xLw0up/1/

```js
var Button = (props) => 
  <button onClick={props.handleClick}>
    {props.children}
  </button>

Button.propTypes = {
  handleClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

class Modal extends React.Component {
  openModal () { 
    console.log('Opening Modal.....')
  }
  childrenWithProps () {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children,(child) =>           React.cloneElement(child, {
        handleClick: this.openModal
      })
    );
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
     {this.childrenWithProps()} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var App = () => 
  <Modal>
    <Button>Launch Modal</Button>
  </Modal>

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. It's extremely difficult to read.

Comment: @dannyid The code is formatted correctly. The Stack Overflow editor seems to unformat it that is why I posted a link to the jsfiddle.

Comment: Why not just render `Button` like `<div><Button handleClick={this.openModal} /></div>` in `Modal` ?

Comment: @hauchengzan Because it is not in the context of the modal. `this` would be undefined.

Comment: What do you mean not in the context of the modal? I don't understand.